# database table not being created in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

I have a working web app developed using jquery mobile, html5, javascript. I created an android project in phonegap using the html and js files that i already had. The application launches properly on the emulator and I can see all the pages are being loaded fine. In one of the pages I have to save form data in the database. I can see the database creation is happening properly but the table is not being created. This is the code where i'm creating the table in the js file,

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exp (
                   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                   ename VARCHAR(30),
                   amount DECIMAL(4,2),
                   category TEXT, 
                   date DATE)',[]);
});
```

I'm confused and don't even know where to start looking as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with the phonegap since I was not even able to run the database example provided by them on the website. Still you can achieve this functionality by creating a plugin for phonegap and accessing the database using the android code.
convert the data from database to json and pass it to the phonegap js file.Refer to  this page to know how  how it can be done:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android